# lua 5.1 translate utf8 russian characters to unicode?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, encode, lua-5.1

Hello I am wondering if it is possible to translate `Привет` into `\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442` in lua 5.1. There is no utf8 library, nor no unicode library inside this game. I've looked for a library on github that does this for me, but I can't find one that is suited for this

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/perfgao/lua-resty-unicode/blob/master/lib/resty/unicode.lua

```
utf8_to_unicode("Привет")
>"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"
```